# Одно шифрование в Python и C#

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, криптография

Пишу чат на Python, где в качестве шифрования использую `cryptography.fernet.Fernet`, который шифрует строку по одному ключу.

Решил написать мобильное приложение, но понял, что лучше его будет реализовать на C#. Можно ли и каким образом использовать это же шифрование в C#?

Comment: А у вас есть [выбор](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Fernet+)?